# Keras layer asks for different shape than in the summary

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm writing a U-net CNN in keras, and trying to use fit_generator for training. In order for this to work, I used a generator script, that could feed the images and labels for my network (simple fit function is working but I want to train a big dataset which cannot fit into the memory).

My problem is that in the model summary, it says correctly that, the output layer has a shape: (None, 288, 512, 4)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzvA.jpg

but when I try actual training I get this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqHnx.jpg

I don't get why keras wants (288, 512, 1) when in the summary it expects (288, 512, 4)

I tried it with my own unet code, and copied a working code from github also, but both of them has the exact same problem which leads me to believe that my generator script is the weak link. Below is the code I used (the image and label array functions used here were already working when I used them with "fit" in a previous CNN):

```py
def generator(img_path, label_path, batch_size, height, width, num_classes):

    input_pairs = get_pairs(img_path, label_path) # rewrite if param name changes
    random.shuffle(input_pairs)

    iterate_pairs = itertools.cycle(input_pairs)

    while True:
        X = []
        Y = []
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            im, lab = next(iterate_pairs)

            appended_im = next(iter(im))
            appended_lab = next(iter(lab))

            X.append(input_image_array(appended_im, width, height))
            Y.append(input_label_array(appended_lab, width, height, num_classes, palette))

        yield (np.array(X), np.array(Y))
```

I tried the generator out and the provided batches has the shapes of (for batch size of 15):
(15, 288, 512, 3)
(15, 288, 512, 4)
So I really do not know what could be the problem here.

EDIT: Here is the model code I used:

```py
def conv_block(input_tensor, n_filter, kernel=(3, 3), padding='same', initializer="he_normal"):
    x = Conv2D(n_filter, kernel, padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(input_tensor)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = Conv2D(n_filter, kernel, padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    return x

def deconv_block(input_tensor, residual, n_filter, kernel=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'):
    y = Conv2DTranspose(n_filter, kernel, strides, padding)(input_tensor)
    y = concatenate([y, residual], axis=3)
    y = conv_block(y, n_filter)
    return y

# NETWORK - n_classes is the desired number of classes, filters are fixed
def Unet(input_height, input_width, n_classes=4, filters=64):

    # Downsampling
    input_layer = Input(shape=(input_height, input_width, 3), name='input')

    conv_1 = conv_block(input_layer, filters)
    conv_1_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_1)

    conv_2 = conv_block(conv_1_out, filters*2)
    conv_2_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_2)

    conv_3 = conv_block(conv_2_out, filters*4)
    conv_3_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_3)

    conv_4 = conv_block(conv_3_out, filters*8)
    conv_4_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_4)
    conv_4_drop = Dropout(0.5)(conv_4_out)

    conv_5 = conv_block(conv_4_drop, filters*16)
    conv_5_drop = Dropout(0.5)(conv_5)

    # Upsampling
    deconv_1 = deconv_block(conv_5_drop, conv_4, filters*8)
    deconv_1_drop = Dropout(0.5)(deconv_1)

    deconv_2 = deconv_block(deconv_1_drop, conv_3, filters*4)
    deconv_2_drop = Dropout(0.5)(deconv_2)

    deconv_3 = deconv_block(deconv_2_drop, conv_2, filters*2)
    deconv_3 = deconv_block(deconv_3, conv_1, filters)

    # Output - mapping each 64-component feature vector to number of classes
    output = Conv2D(n_classes, (1, 1))(deconv_3)
    output = BatchNormalization()(output)
    output = Activation("softmax")(output)

    # embed into functional API
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output, name="Unet")
    return model
```

Comment: We cannot really tell you until you provide the model code.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro I added the model code I used.

Comment: @NeilMarko can you please add your `model.compile` code

Comment: @mujjiga this is the compile code i've been using (my goal is semantic segmentation with the network)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loss to `categorical_crossentropy`.

> When using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss, your targets
>   should be integer targets.